# How can one formulation of the axiom of extension define set equality and the second one not?

Tags: logic, set-theory

I've seen the claim that there are two ways of writing the axiom of extension. The first one is ${\forall}A{\forall}B({\forall}x(x{\in}A{\iff}x{\in}B)){\iff}A=B$.
This one supposedly admits $=$ as a primitive concept. The second one is ${\forall}A{\forall}B{\forall}x(A=B{\land}A{\in}x){\implies}B{\in}x)$.

The second one supposedly defines $=$. How? What qualities does the second definition possess that make it able to define set equality?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, your question seems to imply that the first one can't be used to define set equality ; but clearly it can, and it's the definition that is generally used.

Comment: See [Axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) for the correct formulation.

Comment: For set theory formalized in first-order language **without** *equality*, we can define $=$ as follows: $\forall x \ (x \in A \iff x \in B) \Leftrightarrow (A=B)$. This definition expands the language with the new *symbol* for equality (a binary predicate) and licenses the replacement of the formula in the LHS with the *abbreviation*: $A=B$.

Comment: Thus, being the first formula the *definition* of equality, it does **not** admits $=$ as a primitive concept.

Comment: See this related question: [*Different axiomatizations of set equality*](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644802).